# Cannot convert void to int when checking an int is within a range

Tags: c#

I'm using this code and it's giving me an error saying that it cannot convert void to int:

```
    private static int aBtn;
    public static int ABtn
    {
        get => aBtn;
        set => aBtn = CheckArgumentRange(nameof(value), value, 0, 5);
    }

    internal static void CheckArgumentRange(
        string paramName, int value, int minInclusive, int maxInclusive)
    {
        if (value < minInclusive || value > maxInclusive)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, value,
                $"Value should be in range [{minInclusive}-{maxInclusive}]");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see what's wrong and why it's giving this error?

Comment: `set => aBtn` is supposed to set an `int` value, `CheckArgumentRange()` returns  `void`. Make it return `value` if the range-check is ok, maybe `aBtn` if not.

Comment: Apologies, this is all my fault, of course. I'll edit the answer in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to return the value if it's not out of range. Otherwise the set doesn't receive an int.
So simply add `return value;` after your if and you should be good.

Edit: and of course change the return type from void to int.

```
    private static int aBtn;
    public static int ABtn
    {
        get => aBtn;
        set => aBtn = CheckArgumentRange(nameof(value), value, 0, 5);
    }

    internal static int CheckArgumentRange(
        string paramName, int value, int minInclusive, int maxInclusive)
    {
        if (value < minInclusive || value > maxInclusive)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, value,
                $"Value should be in range [{minInclusive}-{maxInclusive}]");
        }

        return value;
    }
```